# Magento: displaying attribute value in product grid view

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to display supplementary information in the grid/list view of my products categories (see example page (http://marsden.robertobertuol.com/index.php/industrial-scales/bench-scales.html?mode=grid). I manage to print out the meta title as follows:

```
 echo $_product->getMetaTitle();
```

But I also want to print out another attribute namely "capacity". 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why the value was not printing.

In order for the attribute to be available on other pages (other than the product page), in the backend, the setting "Product Listing" should be set to "Yes". 
In this case, it is possible to print the value of the attribute ("capacity") by using

```
 echo $_product->getCapacity();
```

Answer (score 0):

**if attribute is text than use as below**

```
 echo $_product->getCapacity();
```

**if attribute is dropdown**

```
$capacity_id = $_product->getData('capacity');

$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute('capacity'); if ($attr->usesSource()) {

echo $capacity_text = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($capacity_id);
 }
```

**if attribute is multiselect**

```
 $attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute("capacity");
    $exploded = explode(',',$productModel->getCapacity());
    foreach ($exploded as $key => $value) {
        if ($attr->usesSource()) {
             $capacity_title[] = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($value);
        }       
    }

       print_r($capacity_title);
```

Comment: Hi, the attribute is text. I did try the first option (echo $_product->getCapacity();) but nothing is printed :(

Comment: have you saved the value in product

Comment: print_r($_product->getData()); check if attribute is coming or not

Comment: go to product and save the value